# Is it permissible for a convert to care for a sick parental figure at home?

Tags: gentiles, choleh-sick, home-house

Suppose someone wishing to convert to Judaism was caring in her home for a chronically-ill adoptive parent who practiced another religion. Would this be an impediment to the conversion process? Would it continue to be permissible even after conversion?

Comment: This is not really something that is appropriate for an internet forum. This is something that needs to be discussed face to face with a rabbi. Since you say that you are studying for conversion, the rabbi that you are studying with should be able to help you.

Comment: Are you asking if you can care for your aunt in your home despite she being a Christian and you a convert in progress? What might make you think this might be an issue?

Comment: @Tessa, you really need a rabbi at this stage. Google "beit din" and the name of your city or state and you will find one. I can't see how the homecare you're asking about could possibly cause a problem from a halachic standpoint, indeed, I think most rabbis would be extremely supportive. Nonetheless, a rabbi can give individualied advice tailored to your specific situation

Comment: @Tessa, Yaakov, I have tried to edit this question to conform to site rules. Your personal details are very moving, but the way this site works they render an otherwise very important and useful question off-topic

Comment: @JoshK Shavuah Tov. I read your last comment to Tessa. You and mbloch are to be commended for good works. Without creating another firestorm, take note that all the comments which have been deleted by “someone” are mine. That someone has a long history on this site of trying to censor and suppress the views expressed by those that they don’t agree with. Freedom of speech is one of those rights (according to the Founding Fathers of the Constitution) that was bestowed upon every individual, man, woman or child, by the Creator of us all. Rights are something that oppressors (tyrants) cannot take.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for sharing your question. May it be G-d's will to send a complete and speedy recovery to your Aunt and also to give you peace of mind, tranquility of spirit  and the strength to deal with the challenges facing you at this time.

You say that you are "a potential convert" to Judaism. That means that at this time you are not an actual convert, which would present a whole different set of questions. (*It is worth emphasizing that even in a Jewish home, caring for a convalescent non-Jew is not something forbidden.*)

It seems fitting that you should consider the first chapter of the book of Ruth, verses 4 through 8; Ruth whose descendants would give rise to the house of King David. Ruth at that point was also not Jewish. But was praised by her Jewish mother-in-law, Naomi for her kindness both in regard to her dead son and toward her.

In general, in Mishnah Peah 1:1 it emphasizes those actions which have no (limiting) measure and includes acts of kindness among them.

In Avot 1:2, Rabbi Shimon HaTzaddik teaches that the (whole) world stands on three things. One of those three is acts of kindness.

Similarly, Sukkah 49b brings the words of Rabbi Elazar who teaches:

> Acts of kindness, are greater than charity, as it is stated: “Sow to yourselves according to charity, and reap according to kindness” (Hosea 10:12).

All these things are definitely Jewish teaching but are clearly not confined to Jews or the Jewish world. They apply to everyone and in all places.

Your home, if you are single at this time and raising your child, is not a Jewish home. So put that concern out of your mind.

There are no restrictions upon you in any way at this time from caring for your Aunt in her convalescence. On the contrary, it is in your merit and demonstrates that you are a kind individual.

Even if you are in the process of study that will potentially lead to your conversion, that doesn't have to happen by any specific due date. G-d is in control of the world and also your life and the circumstances around it. There is no compulsion upon you to convert at any particular time or for any reason.

Even more than that, at any point in the process of your study (***prior to actual conversion***), if you should have a change of heart and decide that you do not wish to convert, there is no loss. This too will have been ***only*** for the good. Like is taught in Torah generally, G-d created the whole universe in order to bestow good (*to others*).

But this opportunity presented to you now by the Creator of us all, whether to return the kindness and compassion that your Aunt extended to you and your child , and/or to perhaps resolve some spiritual debts that you feel you carry in regard to your Mother (for whatever reason that they may have occurred), is what is immediately facing you.

Moshe taught us how to thank G-d for feeding and providing for us all. Moshe emphasizes that G-d is the *Sustainer of the entire universe through grace, kindness and mercy*. That includes your Aunt. It may be *that you are G-d's vehicle* to deliver that blessing to her at this time.

However her convalescence goes, do your best to be true to your faith and always trust in G-d. Be a source of good (*meaning that which leads to an increase and diversification of life*), support and hope both for your Aunt and your child.